# Merge all partitions back to single volume

Tags: bootcamp, windows, disk-utility, diskutil

I was trying to install windows 10 on my Retina Mid 2015 MBP using bootcamp, and ran into a few problems during the installation. Without going into too much of detail, this is what i have right now, and I am unable to `merge all my partitions back to single volume` and restarted again with Boot Camp Assistant installing windows.

The Disk Util in El Captian doesn't allow me to merge those partitions and I am not very familiar with DiskUtil command to do it.

here is what i have right now
[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually if Boot Camp Assistant refuses to merge partitions, there's corruption in the primary GPT table, and the backup is used. I'd recommend taking a Time Machine backup and repartitioning the entire disk from recovery.

Comment: yup that's what i ended up doing.
just a note, one need to reformat the bootcamp partition in windows installer and wipe out the temp EFI drive before they can install windows 10 on El Captian via boot camp assistant.